# IIS 6 is throwing a "500 - Internal Server Error" for some users but not others

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I had written a mini App in asp classic this week. It worked perfectly on the test server connecting to the test data base. Then yesterday evening I moved it from the test server to the live server updating the connection strings to the live db.

I published it as an application to the default website in the default app pool. Then I tested it and it worked perfectly.

This morning however both myself and another user receive a 500 -internal Server error when we try and save changes to the database(there appears to be no issue reading from the db) yet my two other collogues have no issue at all.

Even more odd is that the same thing is happening on the test server where the code hasn't been changed in weeks. But this morning I cannot commit to the db from there either.

I have attempt to enable more detailed error tracking and logging but the property options for the server are seem unavailable when i tried to set up  custom Active Server Pages (ASP) error pages off online tutorials.

The server is used by a lot of people so I was wondering is their a permission issue depending on the user that restricts writting to the database. Or something else that may have changed to allow some users to write data and others to receive the error.

Im very knew to IIS so it may be something glaringly obvious that I haven't considered.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: I have used explorer and chrome.
I have turned off friendly error messages in explorer all i get is contact admin

Comment: Are you sure you're using IIS 6.0? You should be getting error messages back with that IIS...

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default) should help you:

> In earlier versions of IIS, error messages from classic ASP scripts
>   were sent to a Web browser, by default. Because these error messages
>   might reveal sensitive information to malicious users, IIS 7 and above
>   disables this feature by default. When your classic ASP scripts
>   encounter an error in IIS, you receive the following error message by
>   default:
>
> ```
> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
> ```